# python selenium automatically load more pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying a scrap a website, "www.jabong.com" here for each product line when we reach the bottom of the page it load more products. I want to scrap all the links. The code which I am trying is as shown below:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def fetch_links(url, product_line_name):

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    chrome_path = r"D:\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    button="load-more-products"
    while True:
        element=driver.find_element_by_class_name(button).click()
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)



link_list=["https://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/trousers-jeans/trousers/?source=topnav_women"]
product_line=["trousers"]

fetch_links(link_list[0],product_line[0])
```

The problem here is unable to locate the element. I have also tried with class_name, css_selector but non of them seems to work. I want to load the product continuously on browser automatically.

Comment: This is not the right approach for doing this. Because when you scroll it will show new products and you can keep on going this will increase the data on the page so much that your chrome and selenium will become too slow for you to be handle. So figure out a way to work with Scrapy on this and don't use selenium

Comment: Is the element in a frame?  Post the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will fetch you required data.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

link_list = ["https://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/trousers-jeans/trousers/?source=topnav_women",]

def fetch_links(link):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(link)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    for _ in range(10):   #Adjust this range according to your need, I meant how far you wanna go down.
        actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()
        time.sleep(1)

    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".h4"):
        print(item.text)

fetch_links(link_list[0])
```

Partial results:

```
W Orange Printed Palazzo
DOROTHY PERKINS Olive Solid Mid Rise Skinny Fit Coloured Pant
VARANGA White Solid Palazzo
VARANGA Blue Printed Palazzo
```