# Why is the event dispatched by window not captured by other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, web

```html
  <body>
    <div id="d"></div>
    <script>
      document
        .getElementById("d")
        .addEventListener("test", () => console.log("div"), true);

      document.body.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("body"), true);

      window.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("window"));

      window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
    </script>
  </body>
```

If you run the code above, you will only see one output.

Answer (score 0):

Custom event was only set for window. Try this in your script.

```
<script>

  document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("test", () => console.log("div"), true);

  document.getElementById("d").dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));


  document.body.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("body"), true);
  document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));


  window.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("window"));

  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there is only one output is because you have only dispatched an event on the window object.

If you wanted to have all the console logs, you need to dispatch as follows.

```
document.getElementById("d").dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
```

Please take note that dispatching an event on your div will bubble up to your document. Therefore what you will see when you run the above is

```
body
div
body
window
```

Full code as follows

```
<div id="d"></div>

document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("test", () => console.log("div"), true);
document.body.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("body"), true);
window.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("window"));

document.getElementById("d").dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Because no matter it is bubbling or capturing, the event propagation path can only be from the triggered node to the top level, while window itself is already the top level, so there is no propagation path at all, let alone being captured by other nodes.

So if the event is triggered by the div, both window and body can be captured:

```html
  <body>
    <div id="d"></div>
    <script>
      const d = document.getElementById("d");

      d.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("div"));

      document.body.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("body"), true);

      window.addEventListener("test", () => console.log("window"), true);

      d.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("test"));
    </script>
  </body>
```