# Querying Datastore using some of the indexed properties

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying out Cloud Datastore's indexes, and I cannot figure out the configuration I need to resolve my queries.

I have created a few entities of the same kind (named "object"), all of them with 5 properties named equally (property_0, property_1, ..., property_4). Then, I have created a composite index for that kind, indexing all 5 properties, and setting property_4 in the last place because I want to apply inequality filters on it.

The definition of the index is:

```
indexes:
- kind: object
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: property_0
    direction: asc
  - name: property_1
    direction: asc
  - name: property_2
    direction: asc
  - name: property_3
    direction: asc
  - name: property_4
    direction: asc
```

The queries I am trying to resolve will always apply an inequality filter on property_4, and there may be filters on some of the other properties. Some examples:

- SELECT * FROM object WHERE property_4 > 5 AND property_0 = true
- SELECT * FROM object WHERE property_4 > 5 AND property_4 < 10 AND
  property_1 = 'approved'
- SELECT * FROM object WHERE property_4 > 8 AND
  property_2 = 100 AND property_3 = true
- SELECT * FROM object WHERE property_4 > 15 AND property_0 = true AND
  property_1 = 'draft' AND property_2 = 10 AND property_3 = false

The only query that works is if I filter on **every** property in the index, the rest of them show the error message "Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query."

Shouldn't all the queries be resolved by the created index? Or do I need to create an index for every combination of the filters I want to apply? (i.e. one index for filtering property_4 and property_0; another one for property_4 and property_1; another one for property_4, property_2 and property_3; ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you will need to create indexes for **every** combination of the filter you want to apply.

You can specify the indexes for separate queries in the **index.yaml** file the following way:

```
indexes:
- kind: object
  properties:
  - name: property_0
  - name: property_1
  - name: property_2
  - name: property_3
  - name: property_4

- kind: object
  properties:
  - name: property_3
  - name: property_4
  - name: property_0

...
```