# Is there a way to reduce the white pixels in an inverted image

Tags: python

I'm trying to reduce the number of pixels in an inverted image and I've tried using morphology but it doesn't help much. I'm trying to reduce the number of white in an image, but still leave the outline of the plane.

I'm still somewhat a beginner in python so help would be appreciated.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
    help="path to output image")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())

src = cv2.imread(args["input"], 1) # read input image
src = cv2.resize(src, (1080 , 480)) # resize the image to 1080x480

gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint16) # Morphology to reduce noise

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),1)

# Otsu's thresholding
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)

#Morphology
erosion = cv2.erode(th2,kernel, iterations = 1) 
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(erosion, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) 

thresh = cv2.resize(opening, (1080 , 480))
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of operation did you applied to the image? Please give us more code with sufficient context or [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure you want a threshold here? A filter on only (nearly) black pixels would leave just the plane in this image.

Comment: you can try to use a larger kernel here. Sorry I don't have time to script it.
```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint16)
erosion = cv2.erode(th2,kernel, iterations = 1)
```

Comment: @lammuratc I tried this and I lose the outline of the plane

Comment: If this task is a one-time thing, i.e., you do not have to automate what you are doing now for many images, you can manually play with the binary image. I would use `cv2.connectedComponents` to extract the plane (and additional missiles,maybe). Then, for the rest (clouds,horizon etc.), apply erosion using `erosion = cv2.erode(plane_removed_binary,kernel, iterations = 1) `. Now you have the eroded clouds image and the plane image with thick boundaries, simply sum them up. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. Let me know if this helps!

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


im = cv2.imread('yAgTc.jpg') # read input image
im = cv2.resize(im, (1080 , 480)) # resize the image to 1080x480
height, width, channels = im.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale

ret,plane = cv2.threshold(gray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy =  cv2.findContours(plane,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

im_contour = np.zeros((height,width))
cv2.drawContours(im_contour,contours,-1,255,3)

im_edge =cv2.Canny(gray,100,200)
im_final = im_contour + im_edge
ret,my_im = cv2.threshold(im_final,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

plt.imshow(my_im,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

[image: final image]