# How to add rows in consecutive blocks in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sample excel column as shown below:

[image]

The above image is a resemblance of a single column long table.

What I want to do is: to calculate blockwise summation of consecutive blocks as shown by colors of block size 3. Currently, I am manually going to the top row of each block and using `=SUM(A<row_num>:A<row_num+3>)`. But this is tedious for the very long column. Is there an automated way to calculate those formulas in excel?

Comment: If they are all 3 rows you could use SUM and OFFSET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this formula in `B1` and drag down:

---

***1)*** Before edit - with whitespaces between sums:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()+2,3)=0,SUM(INDEX(A:A,ROW()):INDEX(A:A,ROW()+2)),"")
```

---

***2)*** After edit - without whitespaces between sums:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,(ROW()*3)-2):INDEX(A:A,ROW()*3))
```

---

[image]

Comment: can you pls. explain how are both options working? Your equations looks like some kind of magic. Copy-paste and enter. Everything works. Pls. explain. Thanks.

Comment: Using `INDEX()` we can create a range relative to the position of the current `ROW()`. Whereas in the first option we needed to check if this starting position of the current row was a multiple of 3 using `MOD()` we could skip this `IF()` function alltogether in option 2. For a better understanding, you might want to use the build-in "Evaluate Formula" and go through the formula step-by-step and see how it develops =). Did this help?

Answer (score 1):

If the ranges are all 3 rows you could put this in A1

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,3*(ROW()-1),0,3,1))
```

but the non-volatile approach is better.

Comment: Small note: `OFFSET` is volatile =)

Comment: But if I drag, the next sum is from (A2:A4) `=SUM(OFFSET(A2,0,0,3,1))`. I want the next sum should be from (A4:A5), then (A6:A8), and so on. Finally, to put all these results in a single column to the right so that I can plot it.

Comment: Formula amended.

Answer (score 1):

Non-volatile option:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(A:A,N(IF(1,ROW()+{0;1;2}))))/((MOD(ROW(),3)=0)+(ROW()=1)),"")
```

[image]